# How to prevent ecryptfs from umounting home if tmux is still running?

Tags: ssh, ecryptfs, tmux

I have a server, which i access over ssh. Sometimes i like to run some scripts (some of them in the background) in tmux and then detach it, close the connection and access tmux later.
But unfortunately ecryptfs (or whatever service does that stuff) umounts my home-folder as soon as the ssh-connection is closed. This leads to several errors, because the scripts/deamons want to access some files in my home-folder.

So is there a way to prevent ecryptfs from umounting my home **if there is still a (detached) tmux session running**?

I know that i could just disable the encryption, but i would rather like to keep it and solve the problem someway else.

Comment: Hi there, co-author/maintainer of eCryptfs here.  I'll note that if you have a running tmux session, your home directory should NOT be unmounted at detach.  If it does, that's a bug that I'm interested in reproducing, triaging, and solving.  I tried to reproduce this behavior here, but the test case as described in the question is working for me.

Comment: @DustinKirkland – I assume you're already apprised of it, but you might be interested in this (mildly) related bug: [ecryptfs fails to mount](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x2goclient/+bug/1377924).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to deactivate automatic umounting:

1. Go to the directory `~/.ecryptfs`.
2. You should find a file `auto-umount` there.
3. Remove this file and your ECryptFS-folder will not be umonted at logout.

If you want to do it only at an existing `tmux` session, I'd suggest writing a small script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
    
if tmux has 2> /dev/null; then
  rm ~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount
else
  touch ~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount
fi
```

If there is an tmux session the script deletes the auto-umount and if not it touches it. Place that script in your shell `.logout` file.

Comment: The script doesn't seem to work (i put it into the `.bash_logout`). But removing the `~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` is good enough for now.

Comment: It looks like this script is exactly the wrong way around: it activates auto-umount if `tmux` is running. The if- and the else-statement should be switched.

Comment: @MichaelGoerz FTR, the logic is fixed now and it works as the question title suggests.